# Environment variables not set

Tags: windows, environment-variables

I have the below environment variables on windows:

```
VISUAL_STUDIO_HOME = C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0 
WINDOWS_SDK_HOME = C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A
```

Now I want to have an environment variable `VISUAL_STUDIO_INCLUDES` which should include both the above paths. On doing below, it doesn't work.

```
VISUAL_STUDIO_INCLUDES = VISUAL_STUDIO_HOME;WINDOWS_SDK_HOME
```

How should I declare it?

Comment: Where are you setting the environemnt variable? And how?

Comment: @MD.Unicorn I am setting them manually from My computer -> Environment Variables...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation on [technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772691%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

environment variables need to be enclosed in % characters. be aware that a space between the variable name and the = sign is significant, in other words the space becomes in that case part of the variable name.

```
set VISUAL_STUDIO_INCLUDES=%VISUAL_STUDIO_HOME%;%WINDOWS_SDK_HOME%
```